# Figwheel multiple builds (dev and test) will reload in repl test not dev

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, figwheel

We have a project, and 2 builds:

```
  :cljsbuild {:builds
          [

           {:id "devguidelines"
            :source-paths ["src"]

            :figwheel {:on-jsload "vr.guidelines/on-js-reload"}

            :compiler {:main vr.guidelines
                       :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                       :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/vr.guidelines.js"
                       :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                       :source-map-timestamp true}}

           {:id "testguidelines"
            :source-paths ["src" "test"]
            :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/test/test.guidelines.js"
                       :output-dir "resources/public/js/test/out"
                       :optimizations :none
                       :main vr.test-runner
                       :asset-path "js/test/out"
                       :source-map true
                       ;; :source-map-timestamp true
                       :cache-analysis true }}
```

when I start it:

`rlwrap lein figwheel devguidelines testguidelines`

they both get built however in repl, I get access to testguidelines not devguidelines, which makes repl useless. (Launching ClojureScript REPL for build: testguidelines) How can I configure repl to reload devguidelines not testguidelines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ClojureScript REPL can only connect to one "build" at a time.  If you are auto building two or more builds you can switch the "build", the REPL is connected to by quitting the current REPL. To quit you must by enter `:cljs/quit` at the prompt.

Figwheel will then ask you if you want to connect a REPL to a different build and will list the choices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it really makes sense to run two cljsbuilds inside figwheel; figwheel compiles the code and serves it to the browser - how would it decide which build to serve? Note that figwheel requires at least one build that has `:optimizations :none`, which is the default - so both of your builds qualify.

It looks to me like you're trying to run tests whenever figwheel recompiles files.  The way to do this is using the `:on-jsload` hook to trigger a test runner you've written (like your `vr.test-runner`, for example).

EDIT: you totally can run two builds in the same REPL, try using the `switch-to-build` figwheel function that gets listed out when you start figwheel.  Thanks @user2906524!

Comment: The idea of starting both came from the "father" of figwheel itself: https://youtu.be/j-kj2qwJa_E?t=26m44s . However you may be right to do something :on-jsload.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that, that's ace!